# Finding the complete row of specific number

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

We have a txt file which contains 3 columns and 100000 rows. We would like to find the row of specific number for example: `1.232422567` which is in first column but no idea about the number of its row.
for instance look at following example:

```
...
5.98735973963    4.3453     1.09877345
6.21376876       5.78789    2.11255
1.232422567      0.009044   9.886778893
0.1213445        0.938763   8.9978444
...
```

We want to call `1.232422567` and see its complete row

```
1.232422567      0.009044   9.886778893
```

to use in calculations for example in `h=a+b` where `h= 0.009044 + 9.886778893`.

Please note that: We do not know in what row that mentioned numbers is. We want search the file, find that number and its complete row and use the components of found row in calculation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one way. Output is a `numpy` array.

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

mystr = """5.98735973963    4.3453     1.09877345
6.21376876       5.78789    2.11255
1.232422567      0.009044   9.886778893
0.1213445        0.938763   8.9978444"""

# Replace below with pd.read_table('my_file.txt', header=None, sep='\s+')
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(mystr), delim_whitespace=True, header=None)

res = df[df[0] == 1.232422567].values[0]

# array([  1.23242257e+00,   9.04400000e-03,   9.88677889e+00])
```

Then to apply `h = a + b`, you can use `numpy` conveniently:

```
h = np.sum(res[1:])
```

Or if you want a list:

```
res = df[df[0] == 1.232422567].values[0].tolist()

# [1.232422567, 0.009044, 9.886778892999999]
```

Conversion to floats is handled by `pandas`.

Comment: using `df = pd.read_table('my_file.txt', header=None, sep='\s+')` is probably more relevant to the OP's situation, rather than the `read_csv` with `StringIO` method

Comment: thank you but `h=a+b` was an example, I want to have `a` and `b` separately. and use it in any function not just summation

Answer (score 0):

This is a way in pure python

```
file_path = "numbers.txt"
number = 1.232422567

number_str = str(number)
with open(file_path) as f:
    for i, line in enumerate(f):
        numbers = line.split()
        if number_str in numbers:
            print("{} is in line {}: {}".format(number_str, i, line))
            break
```

Comment: @DeliriousLettuce You are totally right, I wasn't sure if it is a requirement for it to be there, or just happens that in the example the number just happened to be in the first colum

Answer (score 0):

This you can achieve through `pandas` library in python. Here is the sample code for you.

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('filenane.txt', sep=" ", header=None)
data.columns = ["a", "b", "c"]
foundColmn = data[data['a']==1.232422567][['b','c']]
print(foundColmn)
```

Comment: It gives, ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 1 elements, new values have 3 elements

Comment: @Bob That means your text file has one column. For that you can use.
`data.columns = ["a"]`

Answer (score 0):

I see you are talking about `any function` instead of summation. You should call the components of the output array.

```
a=res[1] #the first row is 0
b=res[2]
```

Now you can use them in any function
`h= a+b`

***This solution is based on the chosen answer of this question.***